# Java final variables changes at the execution time

Tags: java

I don't know the reason fo that. Maybe you could help me

So code here creating a frame with 8 sliders.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {


ImagePanel imagePanel;
final int Minimum = 0;
final int Maximum = 10;
final int NumberOfSpheres = 8;
final int NumberOfScales = 10;
MyRandomAccessFile file;

final String[] s = {"Друзья и Окружение",
        "Отношения", "Карьера и Бизнес",
        "Финансы", "Духовность и Творчество",
        "Личностный Рост", "Яркость Жизни", "Здоровье и Спорт"};

private final Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.PINK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.DARK_GRAY};

private final int[] array = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

public MyFrame () {

    setTitle("Wheel Of Life");

    MySlider[] sliders = new MySlider[NumberOfSpheres];
    JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    MyActionListener listener1 = new MyActionListener();
    saveButton.addActionListener(listener1);

    file = new MyRandomAccessFile();

    //String s3 = "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0";
    //array = stringToIntArray(s3);
    array[1] = 4;

    JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[NumberOfSpheres];
    imagePanel = new ImagePanel(colors, array);
    System.out.println(array[1]);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel[] sliderPanels = new JPanel[NumberOfSpheres];
    JPanel mainSliderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 2, 20, 20));
    MyChangeListener listener = new MyChangeListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfSpheres; i++) {
        sliders[i] = new MySlider(s[i]);
        sliders[i].addChangeListener(listener);
        labels[i] = new JLabel(s[i]);
        labels[i].setForeground(colors[i]);
        labels[i].setFont(new Font("Droid Sans", Font.BOLD, 20));
        sliderPanels[i] = new JPanel();
        sliders[i].setMinimum(Minimum);
        sliders[i].setMaximum(Maximum);
        System.out.print(array[i]);
        sliders[i].setValue(4);
        sliders[i].setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        sliders[i].setMinorTickSpacing((int) 0.1);
        sliders[i].setPaintLabels(true);
        sliders[i].setPaintTicks(true);
        sliderPanels[i].setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
        sliderPanels[i].add(sliders[i]);
        sliderPanels[i].add(labels[i]);
        mainSliderPanel.add(sliderPanels[i]);

    }

    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(mainSliderPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainPanel.add(saveButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    add(mainPanel);
}
```

And the output is this

4
99999999

How can final variable change its value at the execution time, what the hell???
Actual value of variable is depend on value that I writing at sliders[i].setValue(4); But I don't know how exactly...

And I tried to set a watchpoint for this variable... Doesn't working. One time its zero and next time program stop in this for loop value is 9, 4 or whatever...

Comment: What do you mean by "the output is this"? Where? You've given us a single class, but nothing to run, etc. A short but complete console app would be a lot simpler to diagnose.

Comment: Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

When you declare reference as final, you can't change the reference, but you can change underlying object state.

You can't change

```
int[] array = somethingelse;
```

but

```
array[1] = 5;
```

is valid.

Comment: Oh, Ok, thanks. But still... In my code I don't give it value of 9. Why can this happen?

Comment: Where you are expecting 9? Can you explain what you are trying to do in your code. Your code is not short.

Comment: 1. Well, that's what's making it interesting. I don't expect 9 anywhere. It is not suppose to be there.

Comment: System.out.println(array[1]); Is this the statement which is printing  output or do you have something else?

Comment: In for loop I am initializing sliders for sliderPanel, giving them initial values etc. I wanted to take initial values form array of int, but there is a problem. Values in array unexpectedly changes.

So I use println to see what values actually there is. And I see that initially it has values that I want, and then for some reason in second or third iteration of the loop it has different values.

I tried to use watchpoint, but with no resulst. One time its right values and at the next stop of the program it is not.

Comment: Is this your full class? Something messed up in your code. array value at index '0' should be first output because for loop started at index 0 and you set value at index 1. But output started from '4'. Is this complete code?

Comment: Nambari, It's not complete class, there is some methods and private classes (listeners), but they are not important.
Value in array is set manually only for debug reasons. It doesn't matter value at what index I would change. It's just to see, that There truly is some initial value, and I changed it successively and then it changed without me knowing how exactly.
So in the output you see '4' and this is value that I've given to second element of the array. And then you see how in loop all values is somehow changed.

Comment: Well, I would suggest remove un-related code and start adding step by step and see.

Comment: Well, I've actually seen one thing already. If I change the place of "System.out.println(array[i]); to

   sliders[i].setMinimum(Minimum);
   System.out.print(array[i]);
   sliders[i].setMaximum(Maximum);
sliders[i].setValue(array[i]);

Then the output is 14000000, which it is supposed to be.
But I have no idea how this two facts are related to each other...

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a variable final in Java its like are saying that the name wont be reassigned something else. Doesn't mean that the contents won't be mutable. The contents of Arrays and Objects in general can be modified.

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("foo");//ok
list.add("bar");//ok

list.remove(0);//ok

list = new ArrayList<String>(); //should cause compile error
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting final to array does not mean that u cant add or change element value, but it means now you can assign another array reference to this variable. But you can add , update or remove the elements in that array